# How to extract year using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, cakephp-1.3

I have textarea where users enter details, I want to extract year from the textarea. The problem is users enter year in different ways.

some users input dates as `1999` or `'99` or `september 99`. how can I use a single regex string to extract year.

Comment: ...and they are not by any chance also entering days and months in the same `textarea`?

Comment: @tim No days for sure. While some use months as sep'99 or september '99.

Comment: This is tangential to the question, but if there is the possibility for information to be confusing when it's entered, the issue is **bad user interface design**.  You should change the input method so that year specification is unambiguous.

Comment: ...and some might write `09/99`, right?

Comment: it might just be me, but this is a problem that I think should not need to be solved. Why would you not lock down the values a user can give that fits a format of your specification...? It just seems a pointless complication of a simple task. @Conspicuous Compiler you beat me too it....

Comment: @all Thanks, Appreciate all your help. It is database that is already compiled I am just trying to automate data retrieval as much as possible. And sort them accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for extracting the mentioned dates out of text:

```
preg_match_all('/(^|\s+)(\d{4}|\'\d{2}|(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december) \d{2})(\s+|$)/i', $text, $matches);
```

This came to my mind, too (it gives the user a little more freedom):

```
preg_match_all('/(^|\s+)((january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december|jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)?(\s|\s?\')(\d{2}|\d{4}))(\s+|$)/i', $text, $matches);
```

All of the above would be easier when parsed with multiple expressions. Why do you need a single one?

If you simply want to parse a string that contains nothing else than this, you should use PHP's [`strtotime()`-function](http://php.net/strtotime).

Comment: +1 for a solution that exactly follows the spec. Pretty sure the spec is incomplete, though :) Hey, I entered `Feb 99`! It's not working!

Answer (score 0):

```
\b\d\d(?:\d\d)?\b
```

will match a two- or four-digit number. So if your string only contains year numbers, that should be enough.

```
if (preg_match('/\b\d\d(?:\d\d)?\b/', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> strtotime — Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp

```
date('Y', strtotime($userinput));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[. -]((?:\d\d|')\d\d)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract only digits from your string :

```
/\b(\d+)\b/
```