# Extract 4-digit year value from a string

Tags: php, regex, substring, text-extraction

I have a year listed in my string

```
$s = "Acquired by the University in 1988";
```

In practice, that could be anywhere in this single line string. How do I extract it using regex? I tried `\d` and that didn't work, it just came up with an error.

I'm using preg_match in LAMP 5.2

Comment: Related: [PHP finding month and year from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61824919/2943403) and [How to extract year using preg_match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4335234/2943403) and [php regex everything before and after year](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15066320/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/(^|\s)(\d{4})(\s|$)/gm
```

Matches

```
Acquired by the University in 1988
The 1945 vintage was superb
1492 columbus sailed the ocean blue
```

Ignores

```
There were nearly 10000 people there!
Member ID 45678
Phone Number 951-555-2563
```

Answer (score 15):

You need a regex to match four digits, and these four digits must comprise a *whole word* (i.e. a string of 10 digits contains four digits but is not a year.) Thus, the regex needs to include **word boundaries** like so:

```
if (preg_match('/\b\d{4}\b/', $s, $matches)) {
    $year = $matches[0];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you *could* use `\d{4}`, but that will break if there's anything else in the string with four digits.

**Edit:**

The problem is that, other than the four numeric characters, there isn't really any other identifying information (as, according to your requirements, the number *can* be anywhere in the string), so based on what you've written, this is probably the best that you can do outside of range checking the returned value.

```
$str = "the year is 1988";
preg_match('/\d{4}/', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: @Jason Something seems off with codepad. The code above runs fine on my box running PHP 5.3.5, so I'm not sure why it's complaining there.

Comment: As explained in the answer, this snippet is not reliable for specifically targeting a 4-digit number. https://3v4l.org/kKvFW

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
<?php
  $s = "Acquired by the University in 1988 year.";
  $yr = preg_replace('/^[^\d]*(\d{4}).*$/', '\1', $s);
  var_dump($yr);
?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
string(4) "1988"
```

However this regex works with an assumption that 4 digit number appears just once in the line.

Comment: This is overly complicated when simply looking for a 4 digit number in a string.

Comment: using preg_replace for a match?

Comment: @Demian Brecht and @Ben Rowe Yes I Agree with both of you, don't know how I interpreted that OP wants to replace the line with the year value. Thank you for voting down :)

Comment: This answer is not reliable. https://3v4l.org/KESRj

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/(\d{4})/', $string, $matches);
```

Comment: This unexplained answer is not reliable for general use. https://3v4l.org/Fo2mm

Answer (score 0):

For a basic year match, assuming only one year

```
$year = false;
if(preg_match("/\d{4}/", $string, $match)) {
  $year = $match[0];
}
```

If you need to handle the posibility of multiple years in the same string

```
if(preg_match_all("/\d{4}/", $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
  foreach($matches as $match) {
    $year = $match[0];
  }
}
```

Comment: This will report false positives for e.g. `1234567890`.

Comment: intuited is correct.  This answer is not reliable for general use. https://3v4l.org/IULN9

Answer (score 0):

`/(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)/` will match only 4-digit numbers that do not have digits before or after them.

`(?<!\d)` and `(?!\d)` are look-behind and look-ahead (respectively) [assertions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) that ensure that a `\d` does not occur before or after the main part of the RE.

It may in practice be more sensible to use `\b` instead of the assertions; this will ensure that the beginning and end of the year occur at a "[word boundary](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)".  So then "1337hx0r" would be appropriately ignored.

If you are only for looking for years within the past century or so, you could use

```
/\b(19|20)\d{2}\b/
```

Answer (score 0):

Also if your string is something like that :

```
$date = "20044Q";
```

You can use below code to extract year from any string.

```
preg_match('/(?:(?:19|20)[0-9]{2})/', $date, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```