# php regex everything before and after year

Tags: php, regex

I have this string which has a year in the middle.
I want to extract the year and everything before and after it.

I'm using the following individual regexes:

1. extract date: `'/\d{4}\b/'`
2. extract everything before date: `'/(.*?)\d{4}\b/';` (i don't know how to exclude date from the result but that's not a problem...)
3. extract everything after date: `'/d{4}\/(.*?)\b/'` (this one is not working)

Comment: You should provide some examples for what you have as input, what the result should look like etc.

Comment: try this /\d{4}(.*)\b/ you left "\" before "d"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$str = 'The year is 2048, and there are flying forks.';
$regex = '/(.*)\b\d{4}\b(.*)/';
preg_match($regex,$str,$matches);

$before = isset($matches[1])?$matches[1]:'';
$after = isset($matches[2])?$matches[2]:'';

echo $before.$after;
```

---

Edit: To answer OP's (Luis') comment on having multiple years:

```
$str = 'The year is 2048 and there are 4096 flying forks from 1999.';
$regex = '/(\b\d{4}\b)/';
$split = preg_split($regex,$str,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($split);
```

`$split` provides an array like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => The year is 
    [1] => 2048
    [2] =>  and there are 
    [3] => 4096
    [4] =>  flying forks from 
    [5] => 1999
    [6] => .
)
```

This secondary example also shows the risk involved with assumptions on parsable data (note the number of forks at 4096 matches that of a 4-digit year).

Comment: Thanks! This suits me.
If i have 2 years in the same string, what do i have to update in your regex to match the first year ocurrence? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
I was looking to match the first year occurrence, so I updated your regex suggestion like this and it worked:
$regex = '/(.*?)\b\d{4}\b(.*)/';